# What exactly does a Pull Request do in GitHub Desktop

Tags: github

Apologies if this is too basic, or a duplicate, but I'm confused here. I can't find an answer in the GitHub help (I did look) and I did ask some software developers (I'm using GitHub to store documentation) and they didn't know either!

Here's the scenario: I have a GitHub repository (call it 'A'). If someone wants to make updates they fork that repository to one of their own (call it 'B'). They can then click 'Clone in Desktop' to get a local copy.

They make edits locally and then open GitHub Desktop.

In GitHub Desktop they can use 'Commit to Master' and then hit the 'Sync' button. This syncs them with repository B. If they want to then copy the edits to repository A, they go into GitHub and make a pull request. I get that.

But GitHub Desktop also has a 'Pull Request' button, and I don't get who it's making the request to! Is it repository A or repository B? Or something completely different?

If it's repository B, then what's the difference between commit/sync and the pull request button?

I can't try it out because that button is always greyed out for me (maybe because I own the repository?)

And can a user make a pull request directly into repository A from GitHub Desktop - or will it always be a two-step process via repository B?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pull Request behavior will be clearer if you start thinking in terms of **branches** instead of **repositories**. A repository may contain many branches, and when you create a pull request, you pick which branch you want to merge into which other branch.

In your case, it sounds like there are two interesting branches so far:

- `A/master`
- `B/master`

That is, repositories `A` and `B` each have a `master` branch. When you see the pull request opened from repository `B` to repository `A`, really it's being opened from branch `B/master` to branch `A/master`.

Knowing that, in fact you can open pull requests between any branches that have a common commit history. For example, if someone created an `A/document_more_things` branch and made some commits (and syncs, which in Git parlance would be a `push` from their *local* repository `A` to GitHub's *remote* repository `A`), the repository might look like this:

```
a - b - c            # master
         \
          d - e - f  # document_more_things
```

Both the `master` and `document_more_things` branches exist in repository `A`, without the need of a forked repository `B`, and the author can open a pull request from `A/document_more_things` to `A/master`. When the pull request is accepted, history will look like this, with a `g` *merge commit*:

```
a - b - c --------- g  # master
         \         /
          d - e - f
```

Whether `document_more_things` is in `A` or `B` actually doesn't matter very much, because Git only cares about commits and their ancestries. If `B` was forked at commit `C` and `d e f` were made on `B/master`, we would get the same picture after the pull request from `B/master` to `A/master` as we did from `A/document_more_things`.

If you'd like to get a better understanding of Git's model, there are a lot of online resources to recommend:

- [Try Git](https://try.github.io/) is a cool interactive tutorial through the basic commands
- [Learn Git Branching](https://pcottle.github.io/learnGitBranching/) is similar, with a great visualization of the repository state as you take actions
- [Pro Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is pretty much the canonical text on using Git (besides the [actual documentation](https://git-scm.com/documentation)), and has a good chapter on [the basics](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)
- GitHub has a solid list of [good resources](https://help.github.com/articles/good-resources-for-learning-git-and-github/)

Comment: Yes, that helps a lot - and the Learn Git Branching link is a very good resource. Thanks.

Comment: not the answer I was looking for but a great write-up about PRs. Thanks.